Is there a way to encrypt an AWS Git repository without AWS having access to my keys?
I want to have a private Git repository running on an AWS instance. This repository contains some sensitive IP that I want to keep as private as possible (even away from the eyes of potential Amazon employees). The problem is that with the solutions I've seen until now everything involves having the key located in the same AWS instance, and hence in the worst possible scenario Amazon would still have access to the data.
Is it possible for me to encrypt my data in a way that only I will have access to it?

If you don't trust AWS's employees and the processes they work within, you're left with self-hosting, with hardware and software you hand-built, guarded 24/7 by you. Very little IP is truly that critical. AWS employees don't have the time, capability, or interest in randomly browsing through EC2 instances looking for your clever idea.

AWS does not have access to the KMS keys you setup.
From https://aws.amazon.com/kms/faqs/:

How does AWS secure the KMS keys that I create?
AWS KMS is designed so that no one, including AWS employees, can retrieve your plaintext KMS keys from the service. AWS KMS uses hardware security modules (HSMs) that have been validated under FIPS 140-2, or are in the process of being validated, to protect the confidentiality and integrity of your keys. Your plaintext KMS keys never leave the HSMs, are never written to disk, and are only ever used in the volatile memory of the HSMs for the time needed to perform your requested cryptographic operation. Updates to software on the service hosts and to the AWS KMS HSM firmware is controlled by multi-party access control that is audited and reviewed by an independent group within Amazon and a NIST-certified lab in compliance with FIPS 140-2.

